# Error reading XMLStreamReader. Getting fault response

Tags: c#, asp.net, soap

i have developed an application where user should fill the application and should make the payment at the end.

To make payment user should fill the details in the link given below.

[Payment](https://k2.karnataka.gov.in/wps/portal/Khajane-II/Scope/Remittance/SearchChallan/!ut/p/a1/jdBLb4JAFAXgX8NS5pSRG-qOhU7FJzYgzqaBBkcSZAhiSf-9Y9NFfbW9u3vzneTkMskSJqv0o1BpW-gqLc-7pDd6mdAYfUwXQUjwSYjRKHIcTMiAzU8gZrEB4ZIHc3oC4P4vjwfj46_8mslLIvpiaBq4TuytOMcrbsBtxSuwjHwDnmM3pNAB6Bv8UjJgUpU6-3rYxq8y7ikmm3ybN3ljHxtz3rVtfRhYsNB1na20VmVuv2u7qCzcC-30oWXJtWX1PkpQjHsy--xOZLodJw!!/dl5/d5/L2dBISEvZ0FBIS9nQSEh/.)

Same details should be entered in the application what i have developed.

When i try to run the code with above details I am getting an exception 'Error reading XMLStreamReader' .

The code is give below

```
public void execute()
    {
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate (object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) { return true; };

        try
        {
            string uri = "https://xxx/Service?wsdl";
            string soap = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
           <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP- 
           ENV=""http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope""SOAP- 
           ENV:encodingStyle=""http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-encoding"">
           <SOAP-ENV:Header xmlns=""http://service.receivevalidatechallan.dept.rct.integration.ifms.gov.in/"">
          <agencyCode 
      xmlns=""http://header.ei.integration.ifms.gov.in/"">EA_DCD</agencyCode>
          <integrationCode 
 xmlns=""http://header.ei.integration.ifms.gov.in/"">RCT033</integrationCode>
         <uirNo xmlns=""http://header.ei.integration.ifms.gov.in/"">EA_DCD- 
         RCT033-31082017-001</uirNo>
         </SOAP-ENV:Header>
         <SOAP-ENV:Body>
         <envelopedDataReq><Signature>-----BEGIN PKCS7----- 
 MIAGCSqGSIb3DQEHAqCAMIACAQExCzAJBgUrDgMCGgUAMIAGCSqGSIb3DQEHAQAAoIAwggNeMIIC
 RqADAgECAgRUDUiYMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMHExCzAJBgNVBAYTAklOMRIwEAYDVQQIEwlraGFq
 YW5lZWExEjAQBgNVBAcTCWtoYWphbmVlYTESMBAGA1UEChMJa2hhamFtZWVhMRIwEAYDVQQLEwlr
 aGFqYW5lZWExEjAQBgNVBAMTCWtoYWphbmVlYTAeFw0xNDA5MDgwNjExMzZaFw0xOTA4MTMwNjEx
 MzZaMHExCzAJBgNVBAYTAklOMRIwEAYDVQQIEwlraGFqYW5lZWExEjAQBgNVBAcTCWtoYWphbmVl
 YTESMBAGA1UEChMJa2hhamFtZWVhMRIwEAYDVQQLEwlraGFqYW5lZWExEjAQBgNVBAMTCWtoYWph
 bmVlYTCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggEPADCCAQoCggEBAIi2iPMHN + 
 4sVbW8mAXu8x2QDtss
 ZU0Qxt / 
 iefTevSygA2m0JTFl1s6BTIP5IOYBTdMeZHPMt8XtnGetuulzCnkFcpp08mAONW5j74xp
  Pv9F0KD + GCFHWEgSOBm2VWH7Ri6g3tkYBT4C9Y3VVPQs3RpzVqm3nn9ERoquiVNih / 
  sWbwgAODjg
   EOeJC6C4G + yowluNKIrbvwTD6Oy7xe17s8qeLSI002DqVZKDhiucJreO3 / VnB5nM3jJLA 
   + PHeVEJ
    iyg0qqbxddXhkAlgyRIDo0kz3c8m0sm8Uh9pqIGHTDL5qwIUfKMA0H9VUoWxqG2u1 / wbMPyKhzjI
 mKNMvqdTTS8CAwEAATANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFAAOCAQEAEzJeM0juQy6LWjtubkHr / XeFVoCqqDoW
 dohMp5eQ / 8rNM1Otuog4ZSp8wgqtW3VGPY0uDJ7BW6SKz / 0XIrlCqRYdM / 
 tSeSTRrXl9fSm8Iaeb
  6rLINT / jnfeYsOFwhB9kSm6lo5 + GY58 / 
  iYATocsCnkofJlRDGJSZhwgBHH4j33N7HUcalj + 8 / 1Se
 lWvb7huqhEaKpBUY00mBJMWFOyPhM7gxNjlUjawnQZuUkCxyFQiM6hyb5O3btNO4B29Hp1mqzHq4
  gVHsGPuID + lvQml7f171BJEDWjTDDeIi6sLTHQO9RUz / 2OkhSRTm2nEYf + 
   4IATiKrO8uqjF1ysxY
  KeXq3gAAMYIB / 
   zCCAfsCAQEweTBxMQswCQYDVQQGEwJJTjESMBAGA1UECBMJa2hhamFuZWVhMRIw
 EAYDVQQHEwlraGFqYW5lZWExEjAQBgNVBAoTCWtoYWphbWVlYTESMBAGA1UECxMJa2hhamFuZWVh
 MRIwEAYDVQQDEwlraGFqYW5lZWECBFQNSJgwCQYFKw4DAhoFAKBdMBgGCSqGSIb3DQEJAzELBgkq
 hkiG9w0BBwEwHAYJKoZIhvcNAQkFMQ8XDTE3MDkwNzA3MjQ1NFowIwYJKoZIhvcNAQkEMRYEFJzo
 8N5KkBJXKAT8yvxMfhsdDFinMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUABIIBADz43QoVuAqLwhUxlVvsM3cV9S0T
 k220X / f55YBYzQYvmdq6lPIRkvrU9OOKQ4Ot4v05VpkbFOlgWuC + ShhqLPCZk + roU + 
 nWYxgqr2kS
 evWIh6zLi + 00X2L2skslzpufbk6kTNtkfJAs8y1AEi4T6Z13ibseT + TMaXWiO58AX / 
 xESJCf3NFI
 q54Tlmh3tg1RBbStRkixU06ZW1Cy8ubTpCVyiJK3BV9uuOD96QNbHEYq8qcMqd07PWxOpRfSsdNH
 mbxwvoajwsE16fswQ8ukZ7EP2R0o5mOAFR2AbmrA809Z5Z + 
  T4v9sjF7QE5lPQriTlBN0k1G3qCNW
   CRXZRKN3qCQAAAAAAAA=-----END PKCS7-----</Signature>
  <data>
 <RctReceiveValidateChlnRq>
 <chlnDate>01/09/2018</chlnDate>
 <deptCode>15E</deptCode>
 <ddoCode>19929D</ddoCode>
 <deptRefNum>DCD1700250</deptRefNum>
 <rctReceiveValidateChlnDtls>
 <rmtrName>Ram</rmtrName>
 <totalAmount>10</totalAmount>
 <trsryCode>572H</trsryCode>
 <amount>1</amount>
 <deptPrpsId>DMD397FB5D7DC06E</deptPrpsId>
 <prpsName>0701~80~800~0~02~000</prpsName>
 <subPrpsName>12</subPrpsName>
 </rctReceiveValidateChlnDtls>
 </RctReceiveValidateChlnRq>
 </data>
 </envelopedDataReq>
 </SOAP-ENV:Body>
 </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>";

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
            request.Headers.Add("SOAP:Action");
            request.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
            request.Accept = "text/xml";
            request.Method = "POST";

            using (Stream stm = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                using (StreamWriter stmw = new StreamWriter(stm))
                {
                    stmw.Write(soap);
                }
            }

            using (WebResponse webResponse = request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    string soapResult = rd.ReadToEnd();
                    //Console.WriteLine(soapResult);
                    string s = soapResult;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            string message = new StreamReader(e.Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you building the XML like that for the sake of this question, or are you actually doing that in your code?

Comment: this is xml what i have used in the code. xml should contain signature and other details.