# How to generate PKCS7 signature in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to generate digital signature in the format given below

```
     <Signature>-----BEGIN PKCS7-----
```
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-----END PKCS7-----

Comment: Ok, what is your actual question? What code do you have for now?

Comment: Please check the link given below.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51685667/error-reading-xmlstreamreader-getting-fault-response