# Is it possible to create digitally signed xml using open ssl?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to generate the signature in the format given below

-----BEGIN PKCS7----- 
 MIAGCSqGSIb3DQEHAqCAMIACAQExCzAJBgUrDgMCGgUAMIAGCSqGSIb3DQEHAQAAoIAwggNeMIIC
 RqADAgECAgRUDUiYMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMHExCzAJBgNVBAYTAklOMRIwEAYDVQQIEwlraGFq
 YW5lZWExEjAQBgNVBAcTCWtoYWphbmVlYTESMBAGA1UEChMJa2hhamFtZWVhMRIwEAYDVQQLEwlr
 aGFqYW5lZWExEjAQBgNVBAMTCWtoYWphbmVlYTAeFw0xNDA5MDgwNjExMzZaFw0xOTA4MTMwNjEx
 MzZaMHExCzAJBgNVBAYTAklOMRIwEAYDVQQIEwlraGFqYW5lZWExEjAQBgNVBAcTCWtoYWphbmVl
 YTESMBAGA1UEChMJa2hhamFtZWVhMRIwEAYDVQQLEwlraGFqYW5lZWExEjAQBgNVBAMTCWtoYWph
 bmVlYTCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggEPADCCAQoCggEBAIi2iPMHN + 
 4sVbW8mAXu8x2QDtss
 ZU0Qxt / 
 iefTevSygA2m0JTFl1s6BTIP5IOYBTdMeZHPMt8XtnGetuulzCnkFcpp08mAONW5j74xp
  Pv9F0KD + GCFHWEgSOBm2VWH7Ri6g3tkYBT4C9Y3VVPQs3RpzVqm3nn9ERoquiVNih / 
  sWbwgAODjg
   EOeJC6C4G + yowluNKIrbvwTD6Oy7xe17s8qeLSI002DqVZKDhiucJreO3 / VnB5nM3jJLA 
   + PHeVEJ
    iyg0qqbxddXhkAlgyRIDo0kz3c8m0sm8Uh9pqIGHTDL5qwIUfKMA0H9VUoWxqG2u1 / wbMPyKhzjI
 mKNMvqdTTS8CAwEAATANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFAAOCAQEAEzJeM0juQy6LWjtubkHr / XeFVoCqqDoW
 dohMp5eQ / 8rNM1Otuog4ZSp8wgqtW3VGPY0uDJ7BW6SKz / 0XIrlCqRYdM / 
 tSeSTRrXl9fSm8Iaeb
  6rLINT / jnfeYsOFwhB9kSm6lo5 + GY58 / 
  iYATocsCnkofJlRDGJSZhwgBHH4j33N7HUcalj + 8 / 1Se
 lWvb7huqhEaKpBUY00mBJMWFOyPhM7gxNjlUjawnQZuUkCxyFQiM6hyb5O3btNO4B29Hp1mqzHq4
  gVHsGPuID + lvQml7f171BJEDWjTDDeIi6sLTHQO9RUz / 2OkhSRTm2nEYf + 
   4IATiKrO8uqjF1ysxY
  KeXq3gAAMYIB / 
   zCCAfsCAQEweTBxMQswCQYDVQQGEwJJTjESMBAGA1UECBMJa2hhamFuZWVhMRIw
 EAYDVQQHEwlraGFqYW5lZWExEjAQBgNVBAoTCWtoYWphbWVlYTESMBAGA1UECxMJa2hhamFuZWVh
 MRIwEAYDVQQDEwlraGFqYW5lZWECBFQNSJgwCQYFKw4DAhoFAKBdMBgGCSqGSIb3DQEJAzELBgkq
 hkiG9w0BBwEwHAYJKoZIhvcNAQkFMQ8XDTE3MDkwNzA3MjQ1NFowIwYJKoZIhvcNAQkEMRYEFJzo
 8N5KkBJXKAT8yvxMfhsdDFinMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUABIIBADz43QoVuAqLwhUxlVvsM3cV9S0T
 k220X / f55YBYzQYvmdq6lPIRkvrU9OOKQ4Ot4v05VpkbFOlgWuC + ShhqLPCZk + roU + 
 nWYxgqr2kS
 evWIh6zLi + 00X2L2skslzpufbk6kTNtkfJAs8y1AEi4T6Z13ibseT + TMaXWiO58AX / 
 xESJCf3NFI
 q54Tlmh3tg1RBbStRkixU06ZW1Cy8ubTpCVyiJK3BV9uuOD96QNbHEYq8qcMqd07PWxOpRfSsdNH
 mbxwvoajwsE16fswQ8ukZ7EP2R0o5mOAFR2AbmrA809Z5Z + 
  T4v9sjF7QE5lPQriTlBN0k1G3qCNW
   CRXZRKN3qCQAAAAAAAA=-----END PKCS7-----

For more details refer my previous question

[Error reading XMLStreamReader. Getting fault response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51685667/error-reading-xmlstreamreader-getting-fault-response)

One more question. How to install open ssl?

Answer (score 0):

In order to install OpenSSL on windows:

- Access the official website:http://www.openssl.org/ Then download the
  "binary" program for Windows: > related > Binaries :
  https://www.openssl.org/community/binaries.html

**note:** *For cryptographic standard operations linked to certificates, the "Lite" version is sufficient. For certains versions of Windows (Windows 2000, windows XP...) you will have to install "Visual C++ 2008 Redistributables" as well.*

**in order to use it on windows machine:**

- The standard installation of OpenSSL under Windows is made on
  "C:\OpenSSL-Win32" and the executable is stored in the sub-repertory
  "bin". To execute the programm via the Windows xommand Prompt,
  provide the full path:

  > C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl.exe ( or >C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl.exe )

please follow more at the [install instruction](https://www.tbs-certificates.co.uk/FAQ/en/openssl-windows.html) guide.

In order to sign and verify text/files follow this [link](https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Sign_and_verify_text_files_to_public_keys_via_the_OpenSSL_Command_Line.html) via openSSL command line.

In order to do this in code use this [Tutorial](https://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2016/09/07/tutorial-code-signing-and-verification-with-openssl/).

There is this [post](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/176002/private-key-to-sign-a-xml-file) in security.stackexchange regarding Private key to sign a XML file using openSSL.

Comment: Thanks for the information. But i am getting the response as  'Consumer not authenticated. Invalid Signature' .